# Not Second Countable Topological Space

Tags: general-topology

[I think I solve this problem using contradiction but in this case I am confused to determine
what is the contradiction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se7Z7.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: For each real number x consider the set `\{0,x\}`. There are uncountably many of them. Each of these sets must be a union of base sets, which implies that there is no countable basis.